# Counter intuitive MongoDB geoIntersects results - small intersecting polygons don't return

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have mongo document with a geofence and a point location defined. I have a user walking around posting their position as it changes.  I construct a geofence around the posted position and try to see if that geofence contains the document's point location or intersects the document's geofence.  I'm getting results that seem inconsistent.

I would expect both of the below queries to return 1 result, however, only the first query returns results.  Although this is not how I would expect a geospatial intersection query to work, it seems as if the geofence passed into the query needs to contain one of the points that defines the geofence on the document, rather than merely intersecting one of it's boundaries.

How can I compose a geoIntersects query such that both geofences return the document?  Or do I need to define the document's geofence differently, somehow?  I have tried both clockwise and counterclockwise definitions for the geofence points in both the document and the query.

[image: The three geofences visualized]

// Document (Black Geofence)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dbb51f8a6c14c000164dfcc"),
    "Name" : "Test Document",
    "Location" : {
        "Longitude" : 55.1165732575153,
        "Latitude" : 25.0430787023156
    },
    "Hidden" : false,
    "Geofence" : [ 
        {
            "Longitude" : 55.1166610906269,
            "Latitude" : 25.0428277929586
        }, 
        {
            "Longitude" : 55.1166610906269,
            "Latitude" : 25.0428277929586
        }, 
        {
            "Longitude" : 55.1166610906269,
            "Latitude" : 25.0428277929586
        }, 
        {
            "Longitude" : 55.1166610906269,
            "Latitude" : 25.0428277929586
        }, 
        {
            "Longitude" : 55.1166610906269,
            "Latitude" : 25.0428277929586
        }
    ]
}
```

// 1 Result (Green Geofence)

```
db.getCollection('MyDocuments').find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "Geofence": {
                "$geoIntersects": {
                    "$geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [
                                    55.11666456834192,
                                    25.042733676877324
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11676242159365,
                                    25.042760017397315
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11680236745489,
                                    25.042823609037915
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.116761597245147,
                                    25.042887200678515
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11666456834192,
                                    25.042913541198506
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11656753943869,
                                    25.042887200678515
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11652676922895,
                                    25.042823609037915
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11666456834192,
                                    25.042733676877324
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Location": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$polygon": [
                        [
                            55.11666456834192,
                            25.042733676877324
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11676242159365,
                            25.042760017397315
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11680236745489,
                            25.042823609037915
                        ],
                        [
                            55.116761597245147,
                            25.042887200678515
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11666456834192,
                            25.042913541198506
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11656753943869,
                            25.042887200678515
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11652676922895,
                            25.042823609037915
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11666456834192,
                            25.042733676877324
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Hidden": {
        "$ne": true
    }
})
```

// 0 Results (Red Geofence)

```
db.getCollection('MyDocuments').find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "Geofence": {
                "$geoIntersects": {
                    "$geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [
                                    55.116678546791337,
                                    25.042891386808234
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11677538065845,
                                    25.042917727328225
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.116814920860168,
                                    25.042981318968825
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.1167745795893,
                                    25.043044910609426
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.116678546791337,
                                    25.043071251129417
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.11658251399337,
                                    25.043044910609426
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.116542172722507,
                                    25.042981318968825
                                ],
                                [
                                    55.116678546791337,
                                    25.042891386808234
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Location": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$polygon": [
                        [
                            55.116678546791337,
                            25.042891386808234
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11677538065845,
                            25.042917727328225
                        ],
                        [
                            55.116814920860168,
                            25.042981318968825
                        ],
                        [
                            55.1167745795893,
                            25.043044910609426
                        ],
                        [
                            55.116678546791337,
                            25.043071251129417
                        ],
                        [
                            55.11658251399337,
                            25.043044910609426
                        ],
                        [
                            55.116542172722507,
                            25.042981318968825
                        ],
                        [
                            55.116678546791337,
                            25.042891386808234
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Hidden": {
        "$ne": true
    }
})
```

Comment: In that object (the black fence) the Geofence field is just an array of points.  Shouldn't that be a polygon?

Comment: Thanks will try and get back.

Comment: Apologies for neglecting to respond, but yes, that was exactly it - changing to a geoJSON representation fixed the issue.  Thank you!